# Bootstrap - Navbar Collapse menu not displaying

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

My navbar does not collapse correctly. When the window is made smaller, the navbar disappears completely and the replacement accordion menu does not get displayed. Ideas?

```
<section id='mainnavbar'>
    <div class="navbar">

        <!-- Header -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainnavbar-link">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href=<%= root_path %>  >
                <!-- <%= t('company_name') %> -->
                        <%= render_logo %>
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Navbar Links -->
        <div id='mainnavbar-link' class="pull-right collapse navbar-collapse">      
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <% Page.roots.menu.each do |menu_item| %>
                                <%= render partial: 'shared/nav/nav_pages_item', locals: {:menu_item => menu_item} %>
                        <%end%>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the hamburger menu button. It does get displayed but you can't see it because it's the same colour as the background.

You need to change the first div to include an extra class if you want to use the default bootstrap navbar:

`<div class="navbar navbar-default">`

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lxkpzwc/3/

Comment: This made the hamburger menu appear, but changed all the colors.  How do I adjust them?  I want the bar, which is the width of the page to be transparent.  The hamburger menu should be black and transparent.

Comment: Added a navbar-custom class in my css and everything is working.

Comment: You will need to include your own css file below bootstrap and add your own css style code. You can over-ride the existing boostrap classes or add your own to the html.

Comment: Just saw your above comment.. exactly what I was talking about :D

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems good. I am currently working on a website that has navbar just like yours, and it seems to me that it's exactly like mine. Just in case, do you have jquery script on your page?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, I have Jquery.  Unfortunately, it does not work.  I added your line of code to the bottom of the page to double check. There must be something wrong with my code or my supporting files.

Comment: Missing opening <ul> and <li> for tags on line 28 and 29?

Comment: removed line 28 and 29, they were unnecessary, but not the cause of issue.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you include every thing needed. and it also mite be disappearing be hind something so just use `z-index:1000` or `position:absolute` to fix this if you go into inspect element it and hover over the `section` or the `div` it should show you where on the screen it is

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom class

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-custom">
```

which makes the hamburger menu visible

## CSS

```
$bgDefault      : none;
$bgHighlight    : black;
$colDefault     : grey;
$colHighlight   : blue;
$dropDown       : false;



.navbar-custom {
  background-color: $bgDefault;
  border-color: $bgHighlight;
  .navbar-brand {
    color: $colDefault;
    &:hover, &:focus {
      color: $colHighlight; }}
  .navbar-text {
    color: $colDefault; }
  .navbar-nav {
    > li {
      > a {
        color: $colDefault;
        &:hover,  &:focus {
          color: $colHighlight; }}
      @if $dropDown {
        > .dropdown-menu {
          background-color: $bgDefault;
          > li {
            > a {
              color: $colDefault;
              &:hover,  &:focus {
                color: $colHighlight;
                background-color: $bgHighlight; }}
            > .divider {
              background-color: $bgHighlight;}}}}}
    @if $dropDown {
      .open .dropdown-menu > .active {
        > a, > a:hover, > a:focus {
          color: $colHighlight;
          background-color: $bgHighlight; }}}
    > .active {
      > a, > a:hover, > a:focus {
        color: $colHighlight;
        background-color: $bgHighlight; }}
    > .open {
      > a, > a:hover, > a:focus {
        color: $colHighlight;
        background-color: $bgHighlight; }}}
  .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: $bgHighlight;
    &:hover, &:focus {
      background-color: $bgHighlight; }
    .icon-bar {
      background-color: $colDefault; }}
  .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-form {
    border-color: $colDefault; }
  .navbar-link {
    color: $colDefault;
    &:hover {
      color: $colHighlight; }}}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    > li > a {
      color: $colDefault;
      &:hover, &:focus {
        color: $colHighlight; }}
    > .active {
      > a, > a:hover, > a:focus {
        color: $colHighlight;
        background-color: $bgHighlight; }}}
}
```